# Trying to call a vector or array into another function

Tags: c++, vector, modularity

I have been learning vectors and arrays, but guessing I am missing something. For assignment I         need program to be modulated and called to main, but I am struggling to find an answer on how to     carry vector/array data into other functions to be used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int getData() {
    int size = 16;
    vector<int> weeklyScore(16, 0);  // initialize
    for (int counter = 0; counter < 16; counter++) {
        cout << "Enter quiz score (0-15) for week " << counter + 1 << " : "
             << endl;
        cin >> weeklyScore.at(counter);  // fill with data
        if (weeklyScore.at(counter) < 0 || weeklyScore.at(counter) > 15) {
            cout << "Please enter a valid score (0-15): " << endl;
            counter--;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << weeklyScore.at(i) << endl;
    }
    return weeklyScore;  // error here
}

int highScore() {  // new function
    int high;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) high = 0;
    if (weeklyScore.at(i) > high) {  // use of vector
        high = i;
    }
    cout << "The highest score is: " << high << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

At this point I am getting error from line 28:

```
return weeklyScore;
no viable conversion from returned value of type 'vector<int>' to function return type 'int'
```

Comment: What is the idea to use this for loop for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) high = 0; to initialize the scalar variable high?

Comment: And what vector is used within the function highScore in this statement if (weeklyScore.at(i) > high) {  // use of vector?

Comment: Functions have limited ways to communicate information to each other. In: argument. Out: return value. The only other option is to use a global variable. _Don't_ do that last thing. Consider this when asking yourself where `weeklyScore` in `highScore` comes from.

Comment: There is no need to use `vector::at()` in this code since the loops do not exceed the bounds of the `vector`. You can safely use `weeklyScore[counter]` instead.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry, I have fixed the high placement so it will work as intended. Intention is vector weeklyScore to be filled in the first function, then checked for highest score by comparing each of them and replacing the current high value by the number checked if it is higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, fix the return type to match the value being returned.

```cpp
vector<int> getData() {
    // ...
}
```

Then call the function and store the result in a variable in the `highScore` function to use it.

```cpp
int highScore() {
    auto weeklyScore = getData();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this allowed me to use the data in highScore(). The issue I see now, however, is that this way runs the input again when it is only needed once, and also will need to be fixed in future functions. Do you know how I would have to edit this to carry over just the vector data?

Comment: @Islandari You could call it once in the `main` function and pass it to other functions from there.